# Why use functors? Cant i just pass function reference instead?

Tags: function, callback, functor

```
    template <typename Fn>
    void do_stuff(Fn f, int a, int b) {
    int c = f(a, b);
    do_something(c);
    }
```

Then  i call:

```
    do_stuff(Add(),1,2);
```

here Add() is a functor.

As i understand this is callback. So my question is why use functor for this purspose?
Cant I create a function

```
    int add(int a,int b){return a+b}
```

and pass reference of this function instead of a functor?

Answer (score 2):

Functors can have state.

How would you convert this

```
struct adder_ramp
{
    int offset;
    int operator()( int a, int b ) { ++offset; return a + b + offset; }
};
```

into an ordinary function?

Comment: ok..so its just for the sake of maintaining a state(in addition to callback) that functor is usd.So if i dont want a state,I can acheive callback just by passing a function reference rught??